# Django] My registration form doesn't work

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I'm coming to you because I have a problem with my form. Let me explain, when I enter the information in the inputs and I click on the button, it does absolutely nothing, without any error message.

This is views.py:

```python
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Movies
from .forms import CreateUserForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required




# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = {
        'movies': Movies.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'list/home.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='login-page')
def add(request):
    return render(request, 'list/add.html', {'title': 'Add Movies'})



def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('list-home')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
    return render(request, 'list/sign.html', {'form': form})
```

This is forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your pseudo:"}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": ">Your first name:"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your  last name:"}))
    email = forms.EmailField( max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your email:"}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Your password:"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Confirm your password:"}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'password2')
```

And my sign.html:

```
{% extends "list/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<main class="site-main" style="background-color: black; color: white;">
    <div class="form-box2">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; padding: 20px;">SIGN UP</h1>
        <form  method="POST" class="conta" style="text-align: center;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.username}}
            {{form.first_name}}
            {{form.last_name}}
            {{form.email}}
            {{form.password}}
            {{form.password2}}
            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
        {% if messages%}
            {% for message in messages%}
                <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</main>

{% endblock content%}
```

So here it is, I probably forgot something but I can't find it, I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: what happens in your browser's devtools when you press the button?

Comment: I get this when I click: "The layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If the style sheets are not yet loaded, it may cause a flash of unstyled content".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new form if the form is invalid, so there won't be any errors in that new form.

```
def signup(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()  # Form for GET request

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)  # add the data from POST to the form
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('list-home')

    # An invalid form will end up here with the errors in it.
    return render(request, 'list/sign.html', {'form': form})
```

Looking at your template, because you're just rendering each field you also won't see the errors attached to a field.

While you're getting this up & running, try to get Django to do the most work for you. There may also be other errors, so you should include those if present;

```
        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
            <ul>
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}

        {# To really make sure you debug this #}
        {{ form.errors }}

        <form  method="POST" class="conta" style="text-align: center;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: I tried what you just put on, but it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Something is happening, you just haven't found it yet. I've updated my answer with non-field error markup & a debug check to output what's in the forms errors. If that doesn't work, it's time to start putting `print` statements in your view to check where it goes.

Comment: Thank you all, I found while posting the errors, it said "password1, This field is required," so I added the 1 to my field and everything works.